# почему js помещает ключи в виде числа в начало объекта?

Tags: javascript

Простой пример.

```js
const a = {b: 2, a: 1, "2": 4, "1": 3}
console.log(a)
// {1: 3, 2: 4, b: 2, a: 1}
//  ^     ^
```

Почему js выполняет сортировку числовых ключей и как этого избежать?

Ну и до кучи интересно, почему не производится сортировка для всех прочих типов ключей.

Comment: почему: потому что так он создан, для нумерованных ключей значения возвращаются в порядке возрастания...........как избежать - не делать числовые ключи.

Comment: это указано в спецификации, для чисел, которые могут быть индексами массива.

Comment: ну и формально, js ничего не сортирует, так как внутреннее хранение значение не специфицировано и может зависеть от конкретной реализации. Специфицировано, только правило обхода по ключам.

Comment: Объекты по своей сути представляют собой неупорядоченные пары ключ-значение. У них нет порядка, так что не ждите, что они его сохранят